# Why do exceptions disappear if I return self in an __exit__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I encountered an interesting phenomenon in Python 3.6. If I return `self` in the `__exit__` method of a class, it seems that any exception raised within a `with` block that uses said class simply disappears. I don't know why it happens and it doesn't seem like desirable behavior. With the following code I can reproduce it:

```py
class SomeObject(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return self


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with SomeObject():
        print('This print statement works')
        raise Exception('This exception is not raised for some reason')
    print('This statement is printed as if nothing happened')
```

This leads me to the following questions:

- Can you reproduce this or is it just me?
- Is the exception supposed to disappear (i.e. is there a good reason)? And if so, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__).

> Exit the runtime context related to this object. The parameters
>   describe the exception that caused the context to be exited. If the
>   context was exited without an exception, all three arguments will be
>   None.
>
> If an exception is supplied, and the method wishes to suppress the
>   exception (i.e., prevent it from being propagated), it should return a
>   true value. Otherwise, the exception will be processed normally upon
>   exit from this method.
>
> Note that **exit**() methods should not reraise the passed-in
>   exception; this is the caller’s responsibility.

As we can see, if you want to suppress the exception, you can return a true value. While an object is evaluated as `True`. So your exception is suppressed.

Comment: I should've checked that before asking 

Answer (score 5):

The way `__exit__` decides whether to raise an exception is based on the "truth" of the return value. Since a class instance will evaluate as True in a boolean operation; the error is not raised. If the return value evaluates to False, the error will be raised.

Comment: "*re*-raised". I think a better way of putting it is that if `__exit__` returns a truth-y value, then it is considered to have handled the exception and it should not be passed on up through the call stack. This is how `with pytest.raises(...):` works.